# What to do with a new external HDD in order to be used under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive

From [a description of an external HDD](http://reviews.cnet.com/external-hard-drives/wd-my-passport-portable/4505-3190_7-35169790.html) for [Western Digital My Passport 1 TB USB 3.0 Portable Hard Drive - WDBBEP0010BBK-NESN](http://reviews.cnet.com/external-hard-drives/wd-my-passport-portable/4507-3190_7-35169790.html):

> There's nothing to setting up the My Passport when used with a Windows
>   computer. The drive is preformatted in NTFS; all you need to do is
>   plug it into a computer and it's ready to be used. If you want to use
>   it with a Mac, you'll need to reformat it into HFS+ before you can
>   write to it. The drive is preloaded with WD Utilities and WD Security
>   for both OS X and Windows. The former is for monitoring the drive's
>   condition, reformatting it, and so on, and with the latter you can
>   turn the drive's security features on or off. Note that once the
>   security feature is turned on, if you forget the password, there's no
>   way you can access the data on it.
>
> For Windows, the My Passport also comes with WD Backup, making backing
>   up data a very easy and intuitive job. You can choose to back up
>   folders and files, or it can automatically back up important data,
>   which is very useful for those who aren't as computer-savvy.
>   Unfortunately, the backup software doesn't include a scheduler;
>   however, you can set it to work automatically when the computer is
>   idle.

I wonder after I buy it, how I shall do with it in order to use it with my Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt its apps will work, but it should work just fine as an external hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the ntfs-3g driver if you want to leave it as NTFS formatted. (if it isn't already there by default) You definitely wont be able to use those windows apps / tools pre installed on your drive.

for more details and documentation : [External USB Drive Mounting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB)

Answer (score 1):

NTFS works well on ubuntu 12.04 but you can still format it in ext3

Comment: If I want to use it under both Ubuntu and Windows, which format shall I go, ext3 or ntfs?

Comment: @Tim: There are some ext3 drivers for Windows, but the NTFS drivers for Ubuntu are much better.

Comment: @Tim - You could use Fat32 if you wanted.  NTFS and FAT32 are supported by Windows by default.  Linux in general has no problem with FAT32.  Support for NTFS really depends on the Linux distrubution being used, even then the driver itself meet standard itself, but Microsoft does not "license" the use of the NTFS format per say.  In other words the Linux NTFS driver might not support EVERYTHING the format actually supports